# Validate user input for dynamically created Text Boxes c#

Tags: c#

I'm creating Windows Forms Application that creates mathematical tasks for children. I have dynamically created a list of 10 tasks represented by labels, and beside every label there is a Text Box, also dynamically created. I have one button "Confirm", for users to confirm all the answers once, but now I want to check if any of Text Box is empty, and if is I want to generate label to say "Must not be empty", keep the button "Confirm", and when user start typing that Text Box I want label to be lost, because it is no longer empty. After user populate all Text Boxes, by clicking the "Confirm" button, app continue with logic based on all inputs.

Here is the code where I check is there a empty Text Box in my User Control called UCFirstLevelAddition:

```
public void submitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool thereAreEmptyContainers = logic.EmptyContainerCheck(this);
            if (thereAreEmptyContainers)
            {
                logic.CreateEmptyContainerLabels(this);
            }
            else if (!thereAreEmptyContainers)
            {
                userAnswerList = logic.CreateUserAnswersList(this);
                userAnswerListInt = logic.ConvertUserAnswerListToInt(userAnswerList);

                al1AreYouShurePanel.Visible = true;
            }
        }
```

My EmptyContainerCheck() method is in another Class and looks like:

```
public bool EmptyContainerCheck(UCFirstLevelAddition userControl)
        {
            
            bool output=false;
            
            foreach (Control c in userControl.Controls)
            {
                if (c is TextBox)
                {
                    TextBox container = c as TextBox;
                    if (container.Text.Length == 0)
                    {
                        output = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return output;
        }
```

So, when this method return true, I am doing CreateEmptyContainerLables() that looks like:

```
public void CreateEmptyContainerLabels(UCFirstLevelAddition userControl)
        {
            int x = 550, y = 180;
            Label message = new Label();
            foreach (Control c in userControl.Controls)
            {
                if (c is TextBox)
                {
                    TextBox container = c as TextBox;
                    if (container.Text.Length == 0)
                    {
                        message.Text = string.Format("Ne sme biti prazno!");
                        message.Width = 400;
                        message.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                        message.Location = new Point(x, y + 40);
                    }
                    else { userControl.Controls.Remove(message); }
                    userControl.Controls.Add(message);
                    y = y + 60;
                }
            }
        }
```

But this does not work as it should be. Can anyone give me a tip?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: In `EmptyContainerCheck()`, innside this condition `if (container.Text.Length == 0)` put a `break;` so that it will no longer validate other textbox.

Comment: Sorry, but that does not help.